# Purpose of form1.designer.cs and form1.resx

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been doing vb.net for a while and I don't understand the purpose of these two files:

- form1.designer.cs
- form1.resx

Can someone please explain them to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*form1.designer.cs* is an auto-generated file that corresponds to *form1.cs*. The idea is that the Visual Studio form designer can put its auto-generated code in *form1.designer.cs* without having to worry about messing up any changes that you may have made.

*form1.resx* is most commonly used for storing strings that you want to translate into different languages so you don't hardcode them into your app.

Comment: Note that the form's "Localizable" Boolean option, when set to 'true', will transfer C# data from the .Designer.cs file into XML data in the .resx file. By default, if that option is 'false', all of the form's design data remains in C# in the .Designer.cs file, and the .resx is essentially empty.

Answer (score 4):

The .designer.cs contains the controls and layout of the form,
the .resx contains stuff like resources and language dictionaries.

Answer (score 4):

form1.designer.cs is a file that is auto-generated by the IDE (e.g. Visual Studio). It keeps all the WinForms related initialization elements separate from the "clean" code-behind form1.cs.

Note that form1.designer.cs is combined with code from form1.cs by the compiler, because the classes are listed as partial, and thus are two parts of the same class definition.