# What is the relevance of *.resx file in Windows Forms/controls?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [purpose of form1.designer.cs and form1.resx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619155/purpose-of-form1-designer-cs-and-form1-resx)

I Understand about *.designer file grouped with a windows form/control file. But not sure what is the relevance and use of *.resx file attached.

Can i not create a form/control with this file attached to it?

Comment: See [purpose of form1.designer.cs and form1.resx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619155/purpose-of-form1-designer-cs-and-form1-resx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Windows Forms designer persists designed forms by generating code.  Lots of control properties are however difficult to express in code.  A form's Icon property or a PictureBox' Image property for example.  Lots of bytes associated with them.  The .resx file format was optimized to store those property values.

A secondary use for them is to be able to easily localize your UI design.  The designer makes it easy, it automatically generates .resx files for each language you support.