# How resx, designer and cs file pass values within the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, resx

In Windows form. There is a xml data in form.resx

```
<data name="$this.Text" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>Report</value>
</data>
```

So in form.designer.cs

```
public System.Windows.Forms.ListView report;
private void InitializeComponent()
{
this.report.ColumnClick += new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnClickEventHandler(this.report_ColumnClick);
}
```

In form.cs

```
private void report_ColumnClick(Object eventSender, ColumnClickEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            if (this.Text != "Report")
            {
                //Some code
            }
        }
```

The question is how does the value in form.resx gets recognised in form.cs. How is this.text getting recognized in desginer and cs file

Comment: You didn't show a complete `InitializeComponent()`, resources are loaded by `ComponentResourceManager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship between `Form.cs` and `Form.designer.cs` is determined by the name of the class and the [`partial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/partial-type) keyword.

You can break classes into multiple parts or files as long as you give the class the same name and add the partial keyword in front of it, when compiling the compiler will see this as one big class..
eg.

The *Forms.cs* file

```
partial class Form
{
 //contain all the implementation code for the form
 //all the code added by the programmer
}
```

The *Form.designer.cs* file

```
partial class Form
{
// contains all the auto generated code
// contains the InitializeComponent() method
}
```

When compiled the compiler will treat both of the files above as 1 class of `Form`.

As for the .resx file, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996636/what-is-the-relevance-of-resx-file-in-windows-forms-controls)

The .resx file also helps Visual studio in design time to keep track of values to display at design time.

If you want to change the `this.Text` in code you can do so in the forms `Load` event.
eg.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string oldText = this.Text; //oldText will be 'Report' or 'Form1'
    this.Text = "whatever you want it to be";
}
```

Comment: Will the value from resx be i18n?

Comment: Thank you. For letting me know the difference. But i really wanted to know how the .resx xml value be recognized in .cs.

Comment: for each language it will create a .regex file. eg if you select a language of French on the form another .resx file `Form1.fr.resx` with the i18n settings will be created.

Comment: As far as I know you can't use it in your code in the same way as using a class. I have never used it in that way. I don't think it works the same way as the settings file which can be accessed using `Properties.Settings.Default.SomeSettingYouAdded` or the resources `Properties.Resources.SomeResourceYouAdded`

Comment: The same form is used in three place and this.Text is getting overwritten. Is there any way that i can compare the overwritten text with the original this.text?. Here i have hard coded as "Report". So instead of doing that can i do it dynamically

Comment: `this.text` is a form name.

Comment: I have added a bit to the answer to show where you can change the name in code if you want. the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/resources/working-with-resx-files-programmatically) explains how to use .resx files. but to be honest I have never used a forms .resx programatically.