# Where are C# Visual Studio Windows Form visual components instantiated?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, resx

Beginning i don't have **`Visual Studio`** because my pc does not support it but i have msbuild and i compile the solutions.
The `form1.designer.cs` make variables receive new instantiated visual objects and later set properties on the `InitializeComponent` method like this

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
        this.tsbtnFuncionarios = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
        this.tsbtClientes = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
        this.tsbtnLivros = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
        this.toolStrip2 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
        this.tsbtnSair = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
        this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.toolStrip2.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // toolStrip1
        // 
        this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.tsbtnFuncionarios,
        this.tsbtClientes,
        this.tsbtnLivros});
        this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
        this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(618, 55);
        this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
        and continue...
```

The problem is when i need to create a visual object visual studio do or edit a existing variable type to make it receive other object type, for example i place a button on form using visual studio graphical layout (i use it on my school) is created somewhere the variable to receive the visual object, but at least as i can see it's not instantiated here nor in `form1.resx` (i don't understand much of what is written on this file) so where are these variables instantiated and/or how can i create new variables or change these variables types.

> [Form1.cs, Form.Designer.cs and Form.resx source code link](https://pastebin.com/jxQTJ1j6)

Sorry i still cannot post more than two links

Answer (score 1):

`Form1.Designer.cs` will have the design controls, their declaration, their instantiation, and their default values for specific properties, like `TextBox1.Text` default value. Visual Studio will manage `Form1.Designer.cs` and update it when the developer makes changes through the WinForms designer.

`Form1.cs` will have the event handlers and constructors for the form. Normally, developers in Visual Studio will put their code here.

`Form1.resx` is not as commonly used. See the below Stack Overflow answers for more details.
[purpose of form1.designer.cs and form1.resx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619155/purpose-of-form1-designer-cs-and-form1-resx)

Comment: thanks i've find the declaration of the it's on the end of the file on #end region, i would never suspect such thing beacuse to me is illogical using before declaring